# Incorrect Frame Position when defined in ViewDidLayoutSubviews

Tags: swift, viewdidappear, viewdidlayoutsubviews

I have an `imageView` inside an `ovalView` constrained with auto layout.

Inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, I am creating a UILabel

```
let label = UILabel(frame: imageView.frame)
imageView.superview?.addSubview(label)
```

The frame of label shows slightly off-centered from imageView.

However, if I move my above code inside `viewDidAppear()`, label is perfectly centered to imageView but user sees the change which is undesireable.

How do I keep my code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` and make it work?

Comment: You're aware that setting the frame alters the origin, being the view's top left anchor? That said, you'd have to subtract half of the label's width to center it on the x-axis.

Comment: Why does it work in ViewDidAppear then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others, who may be facing similar issues. I was able to keep my code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` by adding

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

in my code after

```
let label = UILabel(frame: imageView.frame)
imageView.superview?.addSubview(label)
```

Answer (score 1):

When `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called you can't assume that your views have their final frames before that method is called. In your case that's what happened. When you call `viewDidAppear` your view has drawn all its frames and you get the right frame that's why it works for you. So call it in `viewDidAppear` instead.

Comment: Or in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` if you don't want the user to see the change.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth, indeed. But I would have added it in `viewWillappear`.

Comment: It does not work in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear. It only works in viewDidAppear and the user can see the changes happening (undesirable).

Comment: You really need to show more code in that case. We can't tell what's going on. Like, post your whole VC (at least everything that might matter).

Comment: @Kashif, then your view apparently haven´t finished the drawing for some reason. Either you´re redrawing it otherwise it should work.

Comment: This answer make sense if they change the name to viewAlmostLayoutSubviews instead. Smh.